# tailwind css doesn't apply custom background color

Tags: tailwind-css

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./layout/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./const/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./fonts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,ttf}",
    "./utils/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "brand-green": "#4DF69B",
        "brand-amber": "#FF8656",
        "brand-red": "#FF5656",
        "brand-gray": "#7E7E7E",
      },
      width: {
        content: "fit-content",
      },
      top: {
        20: "5rem",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        DINAlternate: ["DINAlternate", "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      borderWidth: ["hover"],
      textColor: ["group-focus"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

My config.

I changed my next.config.js to to next.config.ts then it told me that it should have .js format I rewrite it and as I think after I tried to move every file to .ts format my tailwind broke. It works with margins/paddins but not with bg though it works with text-red-200

If I inspect elements I can see bg-brand-red classes but it just doesn't apply them.
It worked well but after I refactor code it broke but once I reset everything to prev commit I still get this problem where background colors doesn't work.

It is weird since it worked one time and in 5mins it got broken even when I rollbacked to last commit on github it still be broken

How can I know what is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my global css file where I import:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I moved this piece of code below body{...} and everything works now

```
body {
    font-family: "DIN Alternate", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

To the first thing you should check if the same error occured is how you import tailwind css

I moved body to the bottom since fonts didn't work and it WORKED. Weird problem. I think tailwind just needed some refresh in styles
UPD:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
    font-family: "DIN Alternate", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it worked for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: This worked for me. It really makes no sense why that works...

Answer (score 4):

you are importing and declaring in the wrong order - tailwind has some kind of weird problem in compilation about scss ordering - so instead if body first it should come after components and before utilities.

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
body {
    font-family: "DIN Alternate", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Comment: yea, I  have just put the body where it was and moved tailwind imports to the top and it worked fine. It was a weird problem. I returned to where I had, but there is no problem.

Comment: I did the same thing your doing when I first used it - its okay I guess, when one gets into anything complex imho one still might be better off just using scss or css.

Answer (score 2):

## "PurgeCSS" may be the problem

(you haven't provided usage in the code)

when classes are created dynamically (interpolated), optimizer will simply not export them

### force optimizer to include them always

with exact value:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  safelist: [
    'brand-red', // Add more classes as needed
    // Patterns are also supported
    'brand-*', // Safelists all brand color utilities
  ],
  // ...
}
```

or with regex pattern:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /brand-(green|amber|red|grey)-[0-9]{3}/,
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

Change `tailwing.config.js`

```
content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php", 
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
]
```

to this

```
content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/**/**/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
],
```

and finally run the following command

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: That should not make a difference. `/**/` is used to match paths to any depth, hence the first should match anything the second line matches anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `bg-green` not working,
but when i use `bg-green-500` it now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Any change inside the tailwind.config.js requires the dev server to be restarted. Restarting the server helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you install tailwind css well
you need extra configurations to apply new styles in runtime

I suppose you put your project files in "dist" folder
so if you use npm to install tailwind add this line to package.json in "scripts" section

```
...
"dev": "tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/style.css --watch"
...
```

after that run this command to be able to see changes in runtime on browser

```
npm run dev
```